# Upload Image with Filereader, jQuery, Ajax and PHP. Image too large for Post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filereader

I have a problem sending the image content from client js side to server php side with jquery ajax post request.

I read the file with the following code as dataurl:

```
this.readFile = function(file, onLoadCallback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onLoadCallback;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};
```

and it works fine.

Now I want to transmit the data to the server and save the image, but if the image larger then around 800kB, the ajax request success without sending the data. On php side I got an empty string.

Ajax:

```
function uploadImage(num){

    var data_ob = {
        pic_name : images[num].getFilename(),
        gallery : $("#gallery_id").val(),
        pic_data : images[num].getPrev().split("base64,")[1]
    };
    $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo(base_url());?>index.php/uploadImage",
       data: {
           data: JSON.stringify(data_ob)
       },
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'TEXT',
       async: false,
       timeout: 100000
    }).success(function(e){

    }).error(function(e){
        alert(e);
    });
}
```

Browser: Firefox, Chrome
PHP Framework: CodeIgniter
CSS Framework: Groundwork
jQuery 2.1.0

post_max_size = 8M

Result, small image:
[Picture](http://i61.tinypic.com/xlbgx5.jpg)

Result, larger image:
[Picture](http://i60.tinypic.com/4t0knp.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure that your uploadImage function is executed AFTER the FileReader finished reading the file? Try to debug your code with Firebug or similar (hitting F12). Is the data send with the AJAX request or is it empty too?

Comment: Look at the two images (link on the bottom).
I trigger the upload start with a button and I click it after I can see the images in the browser

Comment: Is all of the data empty in your backend or only pic_data?

Comment: $_POST["data"] is null

Comment: the result you showed in your screenshots don't had the `timeout` set to 10 ms, or? 10ms is a very short amount of time for such a request

Comment: i tried to set the timeout to 100 seconds, but there is no difference.

Comment: There is timeout in milliseconds, not in seconds. So you should multiply on 1000 to get timeout in seconds. Please read manual: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: yes, I read it. now I also changed it in the code above.
But it also doesnt work